# How to assign first element in array to a variable?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm new to c and I have trouble with arrays in c. I don't know how to assign first element from an array to an int variable. When I tried, I got a random large integer from nowhere even index was in range.

This is part of my code:

```
int solve(int *elev, int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        printf("%d ", elev[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n", elev[0], elev[1], elev[2], elev[3], elev[4]);

    int low = elev[0];
    int high = elev[4];

    printf("low:%d high:%d\n");

    // ...
}
```

Partial output:

```
1 4 20 21 24
1 4 20 21 24
low: 362452 high: 7897346
```

What was a cause of above output?

Comment: In addition to Dacre's answer, I'd rid the 2nd printf statement in favor of the dynamic for-loop---assuming you were just testing? And `high` is likely to be `elev[n-1]` (assuming n>0 and `elev[]` is sorted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're not passing the `low` or `high` variables as arguments to the `printf()` call, on this line:

`printf("low:%d high:%d\n")`

If you provide the `low` and `high` variables as arguments to `printf()` then the expected output should be printed to the console, like so:

```
printf("low:%d high:%d\n", low, high);
```

The "print format" of `"low:%d high:%d\n"` being passed to the `printf()` function states that number values will be displayed for each occurrence of `%d` in the format string.

In order to specify the actual values that will be displayed for each occurrence of `%d`, additional arguments must be provided to the `printf()` function - one for each occurrence of `%d`:

```
printf("low:%d high:%d\n", 
low, /* <- the value of low will be printed after "low:" in output the string */
high /* <- the value of low will be printed after "low:" in output the string */
);
```

If these additional arguments are not provided, the program will still compile and run however, at run-time, the program will basically display what ever value is found at the memory locations where it expected to find values for each of the `%d` occurrences.

For more information on `printf()`, you [might like to see this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) - hope this helps!

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for the feedback! - just updated the answer, what do you think? :-)